# Why does my method print "isObjectName=SCALAR(0x1289df0)"?

Tags: perl, oop

New to OOP with Perl, and just had a quick question. I have this function in a class:

```
sub Print{
    my $text = shift;
    print "my text is", $text;
}
```

I try to print the text out, by doing this:

```
my $object = ObjectName->new();
$object->Print("Print this text")
```

It prints this:

`my text isObjectName=SCALAR(0x1289df0)`

My question is, why does it do this and how can I get it to simply print the text I pass as an argument?

Comment: New to OOP? Check out Moose: http://search.cpan.org/dist/Moose/

Comment: Cool, checking it out now Kent!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change your method to:

```
sub Print{
    my ($self, $text) = @_;
    print "my text is", $text;
}
```

When you call a method on an object in Perl (i.e. when you go $object->Print(...), in this case), the first argument passed to the method is the object itself.

Comment: The other answer had great information in it, but i'm going to pick yours for something that worked right away :)

Answer (score 9):

This:

```
$object->Print("Print this text");
```

Is (mostly) equivalent to this:

```
ObjectName::Print($object, "Print this text");
```

The first argument to any method is `$self`, which is a blessed reference and looks all ugly when you print it like that. You want to print the second argument. See [perlboot](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlboot.html) and [perltoot](http://perldoc.perl.org/perltoot.html) for more info.

Comment: I was reading perlboot, just checked over perltoot, and can't seem to find a solution. I'll reread both and see if I can figure out what im doing wrong.

Comment: This section ("Inheriting the Constructor" http://perldoc.perl.org/perlboot.html#Inheriting-the-constructor) deals specifically with what you want.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I was messing around with "ref" trying to get that to work. I'll check out that section now!

Answer (score 6):

When you have these sorts of problems, check your argument list to see what's going on:

```
use Data::Dumper;

sub Print {
     print Dumper( \@_ ), "\n";
     ...;
}
```

You should almost never suspect Perl as the source of a bug, at least until you've eliminated almost everything else.

Comment: Thanks for the debugging info, i'll definitely keep this in mind in the future!